# subquery Problem in Linq To Nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, subquery, linq-to-nhibernate

I have two classes

by Names : Person and Asset

by Relation type : One To Many  (one person by many asset)

I wrote a query by subquery using linq.Nhibernate 2.2

```
var sub_q = from Asset a in SessionInstance.Linq<Asset>()                        
            select a.Person.Id;            

var q = from Person p in SessionInstance.Linq<Person>()
        where(sub_q.Contains(p.Id))
        select p;                

List<Person> list = q.ToList<Person>();
```

I see one Exception in Execution time
Message of exception is : **Code supposed to be unreachable**

Of course following query is true

```
var sub_q = from Asset a in SessionInstance.Linq<Asset>()                        
            select a.Person.Id;
List<Person> personList = sub_qsub_q.ToList<Person>;
var q = from Person p in SessionInstance.Linq<Person>()
        where (personList.Contains(p.Id))
        select p;                

List<Person> list = q.ToList<Person>();
```

But not is good for Performance

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using NHibernate 2.x and not 3.x? The LINQ provider in 3.x is more powerful than in 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
var q= (from Asset a in SessionInstance.Linq<Asset>()                        
        select a.Person).ToList();
```